# Handles variable in GUIDE is not updating

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-guide, handles

I have a GUI created using MATLAB GUIDE. I am trying to return a value from the GUI. Here are the relevant parts of the code (complete code can be found [here](http://paste.ideaslabs.com/show/3L45QfKTL)):

```
function varargout = test(varargin)

% --- Outputs from this function are returned to the command line.
function varargout = test_OutputFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles) 

    % Get default command line output from handles structure
    varargout{1} = handles.output;
    varargout{2} = handles.test;


% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton1.
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

    handles.test = 'ok';

    % Update handles structure
    guidata(hObject, handles);
```

And as soon as I execute the GUI, I get this error message:

[image: http://s11.postimage.org/5trvp5c83/Captura_de_tela_2012_08_06_a_s_12_25_55.png]

I found a [similar](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/259633) question on the MATLAB newsgroup, but I didn't find a solution (and I read all the guidata's doc, like suggested).

My problem is that I recorded an information in the "handles" structure within one GUIDE's function and I can't retrieve this information in another function.

I [tried](http://paste.ideaslabs.com/show/6QQr4NqA4A) to un-comment the UIWAIT call in the `test_OpeningFcn` function in an attempt to wait for the user to close the window.

```
% --- Executes just before test is made visible.
function test_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)

    % Choose default command line output for test
    handles.output = hObject;

    % Update handles structure
    guidata(hObject, handles);

    % UIWAIT makes test wait for user response (see UIRESUME)
    uiwait(handles.figure1);
```

After I click in button, and then try to take the handle variable. But it doesn't work either and [fails](http://s7.postimage.org/5s6lk8tyj/Captura_de_tela_2012_08_06_a_s_12_31_31.png) with a similar error message.

Any help will be welcome.
Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you call the GUI as:

```
>> [a,b] = test()
```

this call returns immediately, so in the output function you try to access `handles.test` which does not exist just yet, causing the error.

There is a [screencast](http://blogs.mathworks.com/videos/2010/02/12/advanced-getting-an-output-from-a-guide-gui/) by Doug Hull showing how to return a value from a GUI. Here is the list of changes to make copied from that page:

```
%%% OpenignFCN
uncomment uiwait

%%%OutputFCN
varargout{1} = handles.output;
% The figure can be deleted now
delete(handles.figure1);


%%%CloseReqFCN
if isequal(get(hObject, 'waitstatus'), 'waiting')
    % The GUI is still in UIWAIT, us UIRESUME
    uiresume(hObject);
else
    % The GUI is no longer waiting, just close it
    delete(hObject);
end
```

Comment: Thank, @Amro, for your attention. It was a good video, but it didn't answer my question.
Like I said, I am trying to update the 
    handles
variable. In the video, Doug Hull taught how to take out an intern GUI variable, but I want to take out my own variable, did you get the idea? I mean, I want to add and variable to the 
    handles
structure and take it out from my GUI.

Comment: @jhow: sorry for the late reply; the idea is the same, you initialize your own variable in the opening function (store it inside the `handles` structure), you modify it in the button callback function, finally you return its value in the output function (the `uiwait` call causes the execution to block until the figure is deleted). Just remember that you have to call GUIDATA every time you modify the `handles` structure..

Answer (score 0):

In the initialization code you have to declare that field.

```
handles.test = [];
```

So you can later call it.

Comment: Thank for your attention, but it didnt work , @copiancestral :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to add in

```
    handles = guidata(gcf);
```

to update handles in different function. 
Hope im correct.

Answer (score -2):

```
global test
handles.test = 'ok';
```